# Controls within user control via code

Tags: user-controls, windows

I have a user control(say control1) with a label(say label1) inside.

I wish to call user control from a form(say form1) with code which will be implemented dynamically with if-else condition.

So i want to call user control from FORM1 and access label1 of the user control via code.

Comment: You don't "call" a user control, you call a method.  A user control is a class, you can give it methods and properties.  Simply add a public property that exposes the label's Text property.

Comment: Sorry..I meant i want to use the user control in my form...and yes adding public property helps.      Thanks